# "Cannot read property 'props' of undefined" while mounting functional Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

**Case:**

I am trying dynamically mount functional vue component inside custom directive
(I need to show special button, when user hovers on some elements on the page). I do it in this way, dynamically, because I have thousands of elements on the page, so I try to avoid excess components and try to mount them on the fly, while hovering.

**Directive code:**

```
import AIcon from './ui/AIcon';
let AIconComponent = Vue.extend(AIcon);

editable: {
    bind: (element, binding, vNode) => {
        element.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
            element.style.position = 'relative';
            let editButtonWrp = htmlToElement(`<div class="btn-wrp"><span class="btn"></span></div>`);
            element.prepend(editButtonWrp);
            new AIconComponent({
                el: editButtonWrp.querySelector('.btn'),
                parent: vNode.context,
                props: {
                    size: 'xs', icon: 'edit',
                },
            });
         });
    }
}
```

**Button functional component code:**

```
export default {
    functional: true,
    props: {
        icon: {
            type: String,
            default: '',
        },
        size: {
            type: String,
            default: 'md',
        }
    },
    render(createElement, { props }) {
        let iconHref = `/dist/img/sprite.svg#${props.icon}`;
        return createElement('svg', {
            class: { 'a-icon': true, [`-${props.icon}`]: true },
        }, [
            createElement('use', {
                attrs: {
                    'xlink:href': iconHref,
                },
            }),
        ]);
    },
}
```

**But on the page I get this error:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
at Proxy.render (AIcon.js?27d5:19)
```

As I understand, when I call `new AIconComponent({ ... })` in directive, it passes undefind context to `render(createElement, { props })` ... but why? How I can resolve this case?

Comment: can you create a reproducible issue and share the link

Comment: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/functional-component-with-vue-extend/40752